# React final forms how to add child forms

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

Have the sandbox with working React forms array
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-react-beatiful-dnd-as-drag-drop-forked-uz24z?file=/index.js:5933-6061

Which in result of click on the add hotspots and  generate the data tree as

```
 {
   "toppings":[
      
   ],
   "customers":[
      {
         "id":4,
         "firstName":"name",
         "lastName":"lastname"
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "firstName":"Clark",
         "lastName":"kent"
      }
   ],
   "hotspots":[
      {
         "hotspotId":6,
         "positionY":"Xhostspotforcustomer1",
         "positionX":"Yhostspotforcustomer1"
      }
   ]
}
```

But I need hotspots to be added as children of customer when click on the Add Hotspot button (to same index of the values.customers array) like

```
{
   "toppings":[
      
   ],
   "customers":[
      {
         "id":4,
         "firstName":"name",
         "lastName":"lastname",
         "hotspots":[
            {
               "hotspotId":6,
               "positionY":"XhostspotforcustomerID4",
               "positionX":"YhostspotforcustomerID4"
            },
            {
               "hotspotId":7,
               "positionY":"more XhostspotforcustomerID4",
               "positionX":"new YhostspotforcustomerID4"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "firstName":"Clark",
         "lastName":"kent",
         "hotspots":[
            {
               "hotspotId":8,
               "positionY":"XhostspotforcustomerID5",
               "positionX":"YhostspotforcustomerID5"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   
}
```

The Add hotspot is added on line 174 of index.js
How to modify the code to add hotspots per customer separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to combine customer field name with hotspot name:

- when you do push/pop:

```js
push(`${name}.hotspots`, /*...*/)
//...
pop(`${name}.hotspots`)
```

- also in FieldArray field name:

```
<FieldArray name={`${name}.hotspots`}>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-react-beatiful-dnd-as-drag-drop-forked-wivwu?file=/index.js

Result:

```json
{
  "toppings": [],
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "firstName": "name",
      "lastName": "lastname",
      "hotspots": [
        {
          "hotspotId": 6,
          "positionY": "Customer4-Y1",
          "positionX": "Customer4-X1"
        },
        {
          "hotspotId": 7,
          "positionY": "Customer4-Y2",
          "positionX": "Customer4-X2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "firstName": "Clark",
      "lastName": "kent",
      "hotspots": [
        {
          "hotspotId": 8,
          "positionY": "Customer5-Y1",
          "positionX": "Customer5-X1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you, you solution clean and simple. Many thanks